# iOS 8 Orientation bug. Works in 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a view which is locked in portrait and then i push a second view where i have it in Landscape.
After the video has played in landscape it returns back to Portrait, which works fine in iOS 7.1 but there is some weird bug on iOS 8.0.

Please look at this picture. As you can see the the tabBar has moved up to the middle of the screen.
[image]

It looks like this before going in to the video player.

[image]

I've tried various other things like setting

```
[self.view.window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

I'm currently using MPMoviePlayerViewController to show my video. But it just won't work after i pop back to the other view.

It's so weird it works in iOS 7.
Can you guys help me out?

The way i'm controlling the orientation is by subclassing uinavigation controller and telling it that it's only in Portrait then when i get to the video view i tell it that landscape is allowed. Then when it returns i only allow portrait again.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to stop it from transitioning to landscape? Also, have a look at the method... can't find it... it's the new iOS8 orientation type stuff...

Comment: Updated the thread with some more info now. Can't seem to find anything in the iOS 8 Orientation doc.

Comment: Hmm... I can't find what I'm thinking of :(

Comment: In your ViewController hierarchy. Do you have one TabBarController with multiple NavigationControllers? Or do you have one NavigationController with a TabBarController in it? Just trying to think what might cause it. The best usage is the former i.e. One TabBarController as the parent and each tab starts with a NavigationController.

Comment: I have a TabBarController which is the root controller. Then i have multiple NavigationControllers. Which seem to work in iOS 7.1. It's just very weird in iOS 8 :/

Comment: Yes, that is the "correct" way.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem, solved by this way. Add this code in your viewWillAppear method in that controller where you are coming back after playing video.

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
 [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
                            forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Then add this method also

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that din't help. The tabbar is stil in the middle of the screen. And yes i did add it to viewWillAppear.

Comment: Yeah i do that to. The way i do it: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES]; 

But that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Apple Documentation, you can control orientation in iOS8 UIViewController only with method :viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:. So, unfortunately, you can't control orientation in special controllers. Maybe I missed something.